# Error "Permission denied @ apply2files" - RUBY language on Windows

Tags: ruby, windows

This error mainly occurs when executing scripts on the Windows operating system.
To eliminate it, you need to elevate the privileges for the files on which any action will be performed before each command.

Example:

MacOS / Linux:

```
chmod +x main.py ;
```

Windows:

```
absolute_path = "./main.py"
grant_permission_projectSettings_file = `echo "" >> "#{absolute_path}" ; icacls "#{absolute_path}" /grant %USERNAME%:(f,x)`
  if grant_permission_projectSettings_file
    ...
  end
```

Comment: I don't understand what is the question. Also, you're referencing a Python file in your snippets; is that relevant, or is the `main.py` just an example of a script file? Where does Ruby come in here?

Comment: the answer is in the question itself.
this is a question with an answer for the purpose of creating a "knowledge base"

Comment: the main.py file is given as an example of an executable file from a script that does not have enough rights to execute

Comment: @MikeRosario - You are welcome to answer your own question, but it is better to follow the Q&A format: Write the question as a question; write your solution as an actual answer. (Writing answers directly into questions does not create a knowledge base - it just confuses people.)